# Clarification with <<< syntax in PHP

Tags: php, html, syntax

I have run across a special version of PHP syntax that I never knew before several times now and it is starting to grow on me. Most of our framework uses `echo` to build pages, rather than continually opening and closing with PHP tags (`<?php` and `?>`); However, this gets extremely frustrating when outputting small scripts and HTML attributes, as we need to be careful about how we escape things, leading to segments like this:

```php
echo ("<form action='$formurl' id='testForm$num' class='hor-form'>" . 
    "    <script>" .
    "        $('#txtInput').clear();" .
    "        if (true) {" .
    "            $('#errorMessage').html('<input type=\"text\" id=\"test\">');" .
    "        }" .
    "    </script>" .
    "    <input id='txtInput' type='text' />" . 
    "    <input id='btnSubmit' type='submit' value='Submit' />" . 
    "</form>"
);
```

Obviously this is absolutely fake, but hopefully gets the point across. I'm not advocating how it is done, but it is what it is. Recently though, I've started to see it done this way:

```php
echo<<<HTML
    <form action="$formurl" id="textForm$num" class="hor-form">
        <script>
            $("#txtInput").clear();
            if (true) {
                $("#errorMessage").html("<input type='text' id='text'>");
            }
        </script>
        <input id="txtInput" type="text">
        <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
HTML;
```

The syntax appears to be as follows:

```php
echo<<<RANDOM_NAME
    //HTML code, possibly other syntaxes as well but likely not
RANDOM_NAME;
```

It is absolutely much nicer, as it actually gives proper syntax highlighting and escaping quotes/appending strings is no longer necessary! The only problem is that **I can find absolutely no documentation for it anywhere!**. It may be that I don't know what to search for, and indeed I don't, but I have only found anything involving it once and I can't locate it again.

I have a lot of questions about it (like can I use PHP functions from within it, or what types of variables can I use, etc) but nowhere to go for solutions. Also, can I do something other than directly using `echo`? For example, can I use a variable instead of `echo`? If so, how?

If someone could enlighten me that would be excellent!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc and heredoc on the same page.

Comment: It's known as "heredoc syntax" http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc  and you can use it in any context that accepts a string, but the ending delimiter `RANDOM_NAME` is fussy about its position.

Comment: Why not to use open-close syntax. For example use `<?php /*some functions*/ if (true) { ?> html_here <? } else { ?> other_html_for_else <? /*some other php*/ ?>`. Did you get my point ot you want me to add an answer ?

Comment: @GeorgeGkas - why use open-close syntax when heredoc is some much easier and cleaner

Comment: @GeorgeGkas If you'll notice I kind of alluded to not wanting to use open/close, but didn't explicity say so. I agree with Mark, I prefer what I now know as heredoc.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thank you, I honestly did not come across that in my searches between work. My apologies for the duplicate

Comment: @KendallRoth No problem. It's difficult to search for symbols, but many of us have a mental map of the landscape of PHP questions to link as signposts.

Comment: @MarkBaker I use it for MVC architecture design. It works for me. Do you believe that I should stop using it?

Comment: The one thing I do not like about about heredoc (and nowdoc) is that the ending identifier must contain nothing else other than the identifier itself and a semicolon. So no indenting for example

Comment: @GeorgeGkas - Use what works in the appropriate circumstance; but dropping in and out of PHP every line over several lines is often less readable and more costly in performance